# Binding event on indicator of the HTML date field to close the built-in date picker pop-up programatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, datefield

I am working on a legacy project that uses jQuery. I am having a UI issue with the HTML date field. See the screenshot below.

[image]

As you can see there are two picker pop-ups there, one for the built-in picker and another one from the plugin. What I am trying to do now is that, when I click on the indicator of the date field, I want to programmatically close the picker. First I am trying to bind event to the indicator. I tried this.

```
$('body').on('click', '#date-field::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator', function () {
        alert('binding successful')
    })
```

But I did not work out. Is it possible to bind an event on it? How?

I will also need a way to programmatically close the HTML date picker pop-up without changing it to text field. Is it possible?

Comment: `I will also need a way to programmatically close the HTML date picker pop-up without changing it to text field` I don't believe you can. Why do you not want to use a text-field?

Comment: Cause it is gonna mess up the plugin behavior and the look of it.

Comment: It shouldn't. Date picker controls are designed to work with text fields. Using a date control makes the entire point of the datepicker redundant.

Comment: Can you provide code example?